# R Most Frequent Factor (yes/No)

Tags: r

I am new to R and working on my first dataset and hence these questions. if its very basic, my apologies.

I have a dataframe(`Df`) with few columns (some intergers, some factors and few texts).

The Factor variables(one for example:f1) all have True/False/NA values. I am trying to replace the missing values with the most frequent value.

I know the most frequent values of each of these factor variables. I found them using `summary(Df)`. But, dont want to hard code or use too many lines of code.I come from database background and I am visualizing the dataframe as a table and this factor variable as a column. Maybe thats my problem!

Following are the options I tried and why it didnt work:

1. `Df$f1[is.na(Df$D1)] <- median(as.numeric(levels(Df$f1)),na.rm=TRUE)`

This didnt work since its throwing a `warning : NAs introduced by coercion`.

2. I tried to convert the factors into numeric using `as.numeric` and find median and recode. But it's converting most of it into `NA`s.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If `colnums` is a vector of the column numbers of the factor variables you want to change the `NA` values of, you can use the following. If you want to change all the factors, just use

`colnums <- which(sapply(df,is.factor))`

```
NA2mf <- function(col.num, df){
    col <- df[,col.num]
    tab <- table(col)
    max <- which.max(tab)
    if(sum(tab == tab[max]) > 1) {
        warning(paste('no unique most frequent factor in var', as.character(names(df)[col.num])))
    }
    col[is.na(col)] <- names(max)
    col
}

df[,colnums] <- sapply(colnums, NA2mf, df = Df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with a little less code:

```
dt = data.frame(x = sample(c(letters[1:5],NA),50,replace=TRUE))

for(field in names(dt)){
    dt[is.na(dt[,field]),field]  <- names(sort(table(dt$x),TRUE)[1])        
}
```

And for later in your R'ing, there are more elegant ways to achieve this with the awesome `data.table` package.